# How to declare an userinput as an info for a list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm making my own encode decode progrmm and for decoding it essentiel for me to take the input of the user as alist

I've tried the join and the list method but they didn't worked for me.

```
c = input()
list(c)
```

I want that when I input the list that I get encoded for example: `[14452, 35627, 1432]` in the code, that `c = [14552,...]`

Comment: Can you share how a sample value entered in `input()` look like

Comment: of course wait a sec

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh ['22099', '29819', '11168', '11168', '93220']

Comment: Are you looking for a way to verify that `c` contains a list?

Comment: @ScottHunter no i want c = the input which is a list

Comment: No that doesn't work since `c` is a string and `list(c)` will give you `['[', "'", '2', '2', '0', '9', '9', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', '9', '8', '1', '9', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '1', '1', '1', '6', '8', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '1', '1', '1', '6', '8', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '9', '3', '2', '2', '0', "'", ']', ' ']`

Comment: i know thats why I'm searching for a solution :)

Comment: So if the user enters `X`, what would go in `c`?

Comment: One approach is to input it as a space separated string `1 2 3 4` etc, and then splitting by whitespace, and parsing each element as an integer

Comment: Then the code will say no hats not encoded text please enter the encoded text which is ['22099', '29819', '11168', '11168', '93220'] for example

Comment: Start by putting whatever you have in the question, it's really unclear what you are trying to do here, add some sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh good idea could you give mes some code how i shoukld do it .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
c = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

input:

```
[123,456,789]
```

then:

```
print(c)
#[123, 456, 789]
print(type(c))
#<class 'list'>
```